# How this integration is solved?

Tags: integration, bayesian, estimation

[Can anyone explain how this integration has been performed? This is a Bayes estimator for uniform prior assuming quadratic loss function. 
Thanks in advance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQwYa.gif)

[image]

Comment: i am not sure how the second step is performed. how the integral is converted into a numerator and denominator???? @RobinGoodfellow

Answer (score 0):

The middle step comes from Bayes' rule:
$$
\pi(\theta | x) = \frac{\pi(x | \theta) \pi(\theta)}{\pi(x)}
$$
where the denominator is an integral over $\theta$.